# Change the background colour of a 'tr' while hovering on the last element in the same row

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the background colour of a table row if I hover the last element on the same row using CSS?

Note: table row background colour should not change while hovering the other 'td'; Hovering effect should be applied only by a single 'td'.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th> 
 <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td id="last-child">50</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td id="last-child">94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in the above table code if I hover over the 'td' having an id of last-child,
then it should change the background colour of the corresponding table row.
How can I achieve it.?

Comment: You'll need `JavaScript` to achieve this, currently, `CSS` doesn't have a 'parent selector'.

Comment: do you use Jquery?

Comment: You cannot have the same `id` value more than once in a document, it has to be unique.

Comment: @לבנימלכה My project is in angular 6

Comment: @connexo brother, i know it, it is just for an example;Thank you

Comment: You can do it with the flexbox/grid and the order property.

Comment: @pepe Always a bad idea to be careless about errors in sample code you present.

Comment: @connexo great advise, Thank you

Comment: @VXp How Can i do it with flexbox/grid?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mucetny8/7/

Comment: Check out my answer. All this stuff is too complex for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @pepe Try out my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Why not cheat like this. Forget the javascript.

```css
table{
overflow:hidden;
}
tr td{
height:20px;
position:relative;
}
tr > td:last-child:hover::after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: -101vw;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200vw;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: did n't work out; Thanks

Comment: So what happened instead? I know the snippet works.

Comment: sorry for the late replay, it changes the background colour of outer div

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: Using CSS you cannot, since you cannot select backwards or upwards in the DOM with CSS.

So if you still need to solve the problem you stated, you will have to resort to Javascript here. In the code example, `e` is the event being passed to the handler function, and the element that the event was raised on is available in `e.target`. From there the methods use `.closest('tr')` to find the parent row (`.parentNode()` would also work here).

```js
let lastTds = [...document.querySelectorAll('td:last-of-type')];

for (const lastTd of lastTds) {
  lastTd.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    e.target.closest('tr').classList.add('highlighted');
  })
  lastTd.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    e.target.closest('tr').classList.remove('highlighted');
  })
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please note that you cannot have the same `id` value more than once in a document, it has to be unique. The ids are also not necessary to find the elements in a selector.

Comment: Works, but the OP didn't tag `JavaScript` he wants a `CSS` only solution which is impossible for mow.

Comment: @ths Well in the first place OP has a problem to solve. If it isn't possible using CSS (which my answer points out and gives reason for), imo it's better to show OP how else they could achieve their goal.

Comment: I know I just want to mention for anyone who reads. I edited the OP's question added the `JavaScript` tag, so your answer fits with the question.